# Cubic splines for interpolation through four points in R

Tags: r, splines, interpolation

I am attempting to write `R` code for cubic splines to connect points on a graph.  Specifically, I am attempting to reproduce Figure 3.3 of Wood (2006) `Generalized Additive Models: An Introduction with R` (page 124) where he uses seven cubic splines to connect eight points.  I am starting with only three or four data points and have modified their values, so they may not closely match his data.

I have written `R` code based on equations provided at `Wikipedia`.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation

I believe I have successfully programmed the equations provided in `Wikipedia` for the example there with three data points.  However, I am unsure whether I have correctly modified that code for four data points.

What is the name of the algorithm shown in the above `Wikipedia` article and used in the example there?  Is there a readily accessible citation for that algorithm?

I cannot see where the equations in the `Wikipedia` example follow from the derivation of the algorithm.  Specifically, where do the equations for `a11` and `a22` come from and what do `a11` and `a22` represent?

The plot created by my `R` code for three data points appears to match the plot provided in the `Wikipedia` example.  However, I cannot reproduce that plot using the `spline` function in `R`.

`Wolphram-Alpha` creates a plot that appears to match the plot returned by the `FMM` method in the `spline` function in `R`.  What does `FMM` stand for and what would be a good citation for that method?

I suspect the reason the plot I obtain and the example plot in `Wikipedia` does not match the plot returned by `Wolphram-Alpha` or by the `FMM` function in `R` is that the example in `Wikipedia` uses two different cubic splines joined together at the middle data point, but that `Wolphram-Alpha / FMM` in `R` create one polynomial equation using all data points simultaneously.  Is that correct?

In other words, I suspect `Wikipedia` and my `R` code use spline interpolation, but that `Wolfram-Alpha` and the `FMM` method in `R` use polynomial interpolation.  Is that correct?

Originally I was hoping for verification that I had generated the correct equations for four data points based on the equations in `Wikipedia` for three data points.  However, I have now shifted my focus to the questions in the preceding paragraphs and removed my `R` code.

If I can learn the answers to the questions above perhaps I can make progress following the algorithm shown in the above `Wikipedia` article and then perhaps post a programming question on Stack Overflow.  Thank you for any answers to those questions.

**EDIT**

So far the best reference I have found is `Numerical Computing with MATLAB` by Cleve Moler, available here:

http://uk.mathworks.com/moler/chapters.html

If I make substantial progress I will post what I learn as an answer.

Comment: You should probably reconsider the whole idea of fitting a cubic spline to 4 points, which will almost certainly result in overfitting.

Comment: This is not a site for identifying problems in code. If you want to present details of your approach as algebra, it may be on topic, but if your question is purely one of programming and debugging, it will likely be off topic here. More broadly, you may be better off describing the underlying problem that you want to use splines to solve.

Comment: Gaussian processes are a flexible class of models to interpolate between points. More specifically, this seems like a case where full Bayes would be appropriate: small sample size, uncertainty about underlying function, etc.

Comment: @Glen_b On page 124 of Wood (2006) `Generalized Additive Models` in Figure 3.3 he uses cubic splines to connect eight points.  I was attempting to recreate that figure starting with four points.  In posting this I was hoping someone could verify that I was using the correct equations, which I think are obtained from first and second derivatives.  If this is viewed as a programming issue perhaps the post could be moved to Stack Overflow?

Comment: I'm not confident that the question in its present form would survive on SO either; to the extent that it's a programming issue, it could be modified to fit their requirements for on-topic posts (see the help there). You may even consider splitting your questions into an SO post and a stats post.

Comment: @Glen_b I have added several non-programming questions in the top half of the post.  Would removing the code to highlight those questions help?

Comment: Not for migrating to SO. If you mean "help it be on-topic here", then probably, at least if they're questions about statistics. [The criterion for questions relating to code here is that it requires statistical expertise to understand/answer.]

Comment: @Glen_b I have now removed the R code to highlight the statistical questions.  I can always add R code later if I post a follow-up on Stack Overflow.  And people can view the R code if they wish by clicking on the edited tab.

Comment: The question has changed so markedly my original grounds for closing are obsolete. I'm not presently convinced the current question is quite on topic, but I'll need to come back later to look at it.

Comment: In addition to this by Moler http://www.mathworks.com/moler/interp.pdf , Chapter by de Boor http://ftp.cs.wisc.edu/Approx/bsplbasic.pdf                                          Book by de Boor    http://www.amazon.com/Practical-Splines-Applied-Mathematical-Sciences/dp/0387953663 After you get done with that, you should know a fair bit about splines.

Answer (score 1):

I have made progress toward answers to my questions.  Here I post what I have learned so far and I can modify my post as I learn more.

Firstly, the best reference I have found so far is `Numerical Computing with MATLAB` by Cleve Moler, as I mentioned in an edit to the question and as Mark L. Stone mentioned in a comment.

I have not yet derived the algorithm shown in `Wikipedia`.  Nevertheless, I assumed my `R` code was correct and expanded that code to handle the eight points Wood (2006:124) used in Figure 3.3 of `Generalized Additive Models: An Introduction with R`.

Those eight points, to the best of my eyesight, are:

```
my.data <- read.table(text = '
      x     y
    0.04   0.60
    0.18   0.01
    0.32   0.30
    0.415  0.28
    0.58   0.79
    0.68   0.27
    0.81   0.70
    0.88   0.83
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = 'NA')
```

In the process I discovered an error in my `R` code, described below.  After correcting that error I discovered that the example in `Wikipedia`, and my `R` code, does indeed reproduce Wood's (2006) Figure 3.3.  I was also able to reproduce that same plot using this built-in `R` command:

```
lines(spline(x, y, method = c("natural"), n = 100), lwd = 2, col = 'blue')
```

More specifically:

```
spline(x, y, method = c("natural"), n = 100)
```

In other words, the `Wikipedia` example is using the **natural cubic spline** as near as I can tell.  Not the FMM spline.  The FMM spline seems to stand for the **Forsythe, Malcolm, Moler spline** described in `Forsythe, G. E., Malcolm, M. A. and Moler, C. B. (1977) Computer Methods for Mathematical Computations. Wiley.`

`Wolfram-Alpha` does not reproduce that plot.  At least I have not been able to do it.  When I use this command in `Wolfram-Alpha`:

```
interpolating polynomial {0.04,0.60},{0.18,0.01},{0.32,0.30},{0.415,0.28},{0.58,0.79},{0.68,0.27},{0.81,0.70},{0.88,0.83}
```

`Wolfram-Alpha` returns a single polynomial:

```
6.29713 - 221.199 x + 2402.99 x^2 - 12051.2 x^3 + 32012.2 x^4 - 46374.4 x^5 + 34557.4 x^6 - 10355.5 x^7
```

Note that this is a 7th-order polynomial, not a cubic polynomial.

I did try to create a 3rd-order polynomial in `Wolfram-Alpha` using:

```
BSplineCurve[{{0.04,0.60},{0.18,0.01},{0.32,0.30},{0.415,0.28},{0.58,0.79},{0.68,0.27},{0.81,0.70},{0.88,0.83}}, SplineDegree -> 3]
```

However, this returns no results.  This might be `Mathematica` code.  Regardless, the `Wolfram-Alpha` code I have tried does not return a natural cubic spline.

Once I derive the example equations in `Wikipedia` I will post my interpretation of them, in particular regarding `a11` and `a22`.  My limited understanding of the difference between the splines `R` offers is that it has to do with how they treat the second derivative of the first and last cubic spline.

Lastly, for now, regarding the error in my R code, the line:

```
a33 = 2 * ((1 / (x[3] - x[2])) + (1 / (x[3] - x[2])))
```

should have been.

```
a33 = 2 * ((1 / (x[3] - x[2])) + (1 / (x[4] - x[3])))
```